# How can i force remove a docker container using 'docker_container' module of Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-2.x, dockerpy

I am having problems removing containers from my docker host after introducing cadvisor - https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/771

I have a large number of Ansible (2.2.1.0) scripts that i use to install my service containers on these docker host and internally they are using the docker_container module. Many times these scripts would want to remove a container, but because of the problem stated above, they are failing.

I can force kill docker container on these docker hosts easily:

```
docker rm container_name -fv
```

So i would expect that the force_kill option provided in the docker_container module ([docker_container module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html)) should be able to do the same:

```
- name: Delete  docker containers
  docker_container:
    name: "container_name"
    force_kill: true
    keep_volumes: false
    state: absent
```

But the script fail always. I do not know what is the purpose of this option if it is not able to force kill it. All of my scripts are failing even after enabling force_kill and i need to know how to make sure this option works as intended ?

Update:
I now understand the force_kill option is sending the docker kill signal. I have updated the question to better reflect what i really want to achieve.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

I think `force_kill` sends a kill signal as [docker kill](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/#usage) so

> The main process inside the container will be sent SIGKILL, or any
>   signal specified with option --signal.

I would check CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile of the image (if you used it) because

> ENTRYPOINT and CMD in the shell form run as a subcommand of /bin/sh
>   -c, which does not pass signals. This means that the executable is not the container’s PID 1 and does not receive Unix signals.

```
CMD ["/init.sh"] # exec form
CMD /init.sh     # shell form
```

Not sure this is the reason of your problem, but may be that a CMD in shell form doesn't forward the signal to your command.

As for [Dominique Burton's blog](https://blog.confirm.ch/sending-signals-docker-container/)

> Always use the exec form if you want Docker to forward signals to your
>   (sub-)process. This is not only important for sending custom signals
>   to a Docker container, it’s also important to properly stop (i.e.
>   docker stop) a container.

Comment: That clears out a lot. I have updated the question to better reflect what i want.